# Proving properties of complex numbers without assuming it is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, solution-verification

The question I'm trying to solve asks to prove the following properties of complex numbers WITHOUT assuming that the set of complex numbers, $\mathbb{C}$ is a field:

Assuming that $(a + bi) + (c + di) = (a + c) + (b + d)i$ and $(a + bi)(c + di) = (ac - bd) + (bc + ad)i$, and defining $z' = a - bi = a + (-bi)$ to be the complex conjugate of $z = a + bi$, prove the following:

1. $(z + w)' = z' + w'$
2. $(z ∙ w)' = z' ∙ w'$
3. $z'' = z$
4. $z + z' = 2Re(z) + 0i$
5. $z - z' = 0 + 2iIm(z)$
6. $z ∙ z' = |z|^2 + 0i$

I've written proofs for all of these properties but what scares me is the statement "WITHOUT assuming $\mathbb{C}$ is a field".
My proofs are pretty straightforward:

1.
$z + w = (a + bi) + (c + di) = (a + c) + (b + d)i$

$(z + w)' = (a + c) - (b + d)i$

$z' + w' = (a - bi) + (c - di) = (a + c) - (b + d)i = (z + w)'$

2.
$z ∙ w = (a + bi)(c + di) = (ac - bd) + (bc + ad)i$

$(z ∙ w)' = (ac - bd) - (bc + ad)i$

$z' ∙ w' = (a - bi)(c - di) = (ac - bd) - (bc + ad)i = (z ∙ w)'$

3.
Let $t = z' = a - bi$

Then $t' = a + bi = (z')' = z$

4.
$z + z' = (a + bi) + (a - bi) = 2a$

$2Re(z) = 2(a) = 2a = z + z'$

5.
$z - z' = (a + bi) - (a - bi) = 2bi$

$2iIm(z) = 2(bi) = 2bi = z - z'$

6.
$z ∙ z' = (a + bi)(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2$

$|z|^2 = \sqrt{Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = z ∙ z'$

I know these are fundamentally correct, but would they suffice for a proof? More importantly, do these work without making the assumption that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field?
Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: A pedantic comment: "not assuming that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field" is different from "assuming that $\mathbb{C}$ is _not_ a field": the first assumption (or non-assumption) just means you might have to work harder, while the second assumption is clearly misled since $\mathbb{C}$ is in fact a field. Your proofs look good to me: I'm not actually sure how the assumption that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field would help on any of these, since the field axioms for $\mathbb{C}$ don't really feature anywhere (the field axioms for $\mathbb{R}$ do, however).

Comment: My bad! I meant to say that you may not assume that it is a field...I've made changes to the post accordingly.

Comment: And thanks for your response!

Comment: You are allowed to assume $\mathbb R$ is a field.  I wouldn't worry too much about assuming $\mathbb C$ is a field.  This is all new that you aren't likely to.  The most likely mistake you write is to assume if $z =a+bi$ then $-z = -a-bi$. and .... hmm, I'm probably being more picky than you text is as I'd claim $z - w$ is not defined.  Defining it as $-z = -(a+bi) = -a - bi = (-a)+(-b)i$ would be fine (but don't assume $z - z = 0$ without proof!) I don't have any problem with what you have written.

Comment: That makes sense @fleablood. And yes, I am assuming $\mathbb{R}$ is a field. Thanks!